# SQL check for values that are missing based on a list

Tags: sql

Bear with me on this one

2 Tables are joined as in the image below.

[image]

Chassis ID 100 & 300 has a Module ID of 29.

However Chassis ID 200 Module ID is NULL

This is for Auditing purposes to make sure all Chassis ID has a Module ID of 29 and if it doesn't have this then display NULL

Comment: Please provide sample data and desires results *as text tables* in the question.  I can't figure out what you are asking.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IkqFZpE.png

Comment: seems you need to use a `left` or `right` join, but without clearly stated sample data, we cannot say more.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to display all rows from `chassis` table then use `left join` as shown below -

```
SELECT *
FROM CHASSIS C
LEFT JOIN CHASSIS_MODULE CM ON CM.chassis_id = C.chassis_id
```

If you want to display `chassis` whose `module` is missing then try below query-

```
SELECT *
FROM CHASSIS C
LEFT JOIN CHASSIS_MODULE CM ON CM.chassis_id = C.chassis_id
WHERE CM.module_id IS NULL;
```